# how can ireport hide duplicated row automatically ? (part of duplicated information)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport

[image: Hide part of the duplicated information]

Please refer to the sample image above, how can I implement that ?  While at the same time change least code ?

I know I can use isPrintRepeatedValues, but I have two column, while sometimes maybe one column is the same, but the other column is different, so isPrintRepeatedValues seems will not work.

Comment: If I use group, can the layout still the same ?

Comment: Yes, the layout can remain completely unchanged. (Do not add a group header or group footer.)

Answer (score 5):

Use grouping on `Staff Name` and `Date`. The layout can stay the same. Just make sure the Group is only printed when the group changes.

Comment: People sometimes don't realize that you have add groups without adding group headers and footers. But you can. Brett's suggestion is perfect for this requirement.